# Override controller multiple time

Tags: module

I'm having a 3rd party module that extends some controller (after updating from previous version that used to do it in a separate controller) that I need to extend with my own module already. Both have a completely different set of actions.

Is there a way to use both extensions (3rd party and own) without colliding?

Comment: If you are sure to have that extension working on the site all the time, you can re-write that controller instead of the core controller.

Answer (score 4):

If both of them rewrite the same action you won't be able to use them independently.
You will have to make your controller extend the extension controller.
if they don't rewrite the same actions you should be able to do it by adding this in the config.xml of each module:

```
<config>
    <admin><!-- or frontend-->
        <routers>
            <[route_to_extend]><!--example: checkout->
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <[module_name_here] before="Mage_[CoreModule]">[Namespace]_[Module]</[module_name_here]>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </[route_to_extend]>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```